# One to many mapping in Cassandra(Ecomerce data schema)

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, data-modeling

i am new to cassandra db and i am making simple ecommerce schema. In relational world we have following schema like
Category table (id,name),
Product table (id,categoryId,name,price,discounted_price)

so in cassandra how can i model my data if i have following queries

1. select all categories;
2. select all products;
3. select specific product with category name
4. select specific categories with their products

And if i update category name does it impact to all tables?

Comment: I would not recommend to use Cassandra for your use case, because:  - "select all" queries -  Cassandra is a distributed DB, and it will work good only if you have query criterias, which allow Cassndra define where data is placed. Full scan query is not a good idea for distributed DBs, since it will involve requesting for all nodes.  - "update" queries and relational data. Cassndra does not provide transactional mechanism, so it can be a problem to keep data consistency between several tables

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible data model:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    category_id text,
    category_name text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id)
)

CREATE TABLE products (
    product_id text,
    category_id text,
    product_name text,
    category_name text,
    price decimal,
    discounted_price decimal,
    PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
)

CREATE TABLE products_by_category (
    category_id text,
    product_id text,
    product_name text,
    category_name text,
    PRIMARY KEY ((category_id),product_id)
)
```

To get a list of categories:

```
SELECT category_name FROM categories
```

It's a full table scan which should be fine unless you have hundreds of categories.

To get a list of products:

```
SELECT product_name FROM products
```

As above, this is also a full table scan and will be problematic if you have thousands of products and/or a large cluster.

To select a specific product with the category name:

```
SELECT product_name, category_name FROM products WHERE product_id = ?
```

To get a list of products for a category:

```
SELECT category_name, product_name FROM products_by_category WHERE category_id = ?
```

Cheers!

Comment: and what about if i update one category name in category table? will it impact on all tables?

Comment: and if i update one product name in products table will it impact on products by category table?

Comment: Yes, you have to use BATCH statements to keep all tables in sync. Cheers!